# How to add argument values with underscore in Azure DevOps PowerShell Pipeline task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps Pipeline with multiple arguments to create a VM

```
    
task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription – MPN(07f41212-2053-434e-XXXX)'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CreateNewVMforImage.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: -azSubscriptionId "07f41212-2053-434e-XXXXX" -azResourceGroupName "AZREUSMGMTRG" -azSnapshotName "SNAPSHOT2GOOD" -azNewOSDiskName "ImageOSDisk5"  -azVMLocation "eastus" -azVMNetwork "MGMTVNET" -azVMName "AZREUSLSIMG6" 
    
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
    pwsh: true
```

If I add the below two arguments values the Pipeline Execution Error Out and I understand this is happening due to underscore, because other values are without any underscore in it and that has no problems. Only when the value has underscore like this below it's giving the error at the time of pipeline execution.

```
    -azVMStorageType "Standard_LRS"
    -azVMSize "Standard_B2ms"
```

This is the error text.

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts an argument
```

My question is how can I add argument values with underscores in it in the pipeline YAML file?

The PS parameters are like as below

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    
#Subscription ID
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $azSubscriptionId,
    
    #ResourceGroupName
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $azResourceGroupName,

    #MotherSnapshotName
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $azSnapshotName,

    #NewVMOSDiskName
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $azNewOSDiskName,

    #VM Storage Type 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $azVMStorageType,

    #VM Location
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $azVMLocation,

    #VM Network
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $azVMNetwork,

    #VM Name
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $azVMName,

    #VM Size
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $azVMSize

)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be useful to provide the error text.

Comment: Hi @askwizard, I can successfully use _ in argument. Could you please delete the underscores and try it again, then kindly share the result here? In addition, please also set the variable system.debug to true and then share the full detail log here. Thanks.

Comment: The arguments without those two values can able to create the VM, only problem when I add those two argument values in yaml file.

Comment: Hi @askwizard, Which agent are you using, hosted agent or self-hosted agent? Could you please share the full .ps1 file and detail log with us? I need check the log and help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#variable-characters): User-defined variables can consist of letters, numbers, ., and _ characters.
I can successfully use add argument values with underscores in it in the pipeline YAML file.
Sample:

powershell.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    
    #Subscription ID
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $test01,
    
    #ResourceGroupName
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $test02,

    #MotherSnapshotName
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $test03

)

 Write-Host "test01 is" $test01
 Write-Host "test02 is" $test02
 Write-Host "test03 is" $test03
```

YAML build:

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Microsoft Azure Internal Consumption (daaeef3e-d7fe-49e8-baaa-b3df9d072825)'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: 'powershell.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-test01 "test" -test02 "Just_a_test" -test03 "Just a test"'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

And result:

[image]